# delete file thumbnail from dropzone

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

Below is the code which I use to upload images through dropzone.

```
<script>

  Dropzone.options.uploaddeadlineimages = {

  // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
  // The configuration 
    paramName: 'files',       
    url:"<?=base_url()."Product/upload_listing_images";?>",
    dictDefaultMessage: "<img src='<?=base_url()."public/images/";?>/frontend/camera-black.png'><h2>Drag and drop your photos here to upload</h2><p><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Or Click here to browse for photos</a></p>",   
    uploadMultiple: false,
    createImageThumbnails: true,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    parallelUploads:100,
    dictInvalidFileType:'Please upload only valid file type(png,jpg,gif,pdf)',
    clickable:true,
    maxFiles:100,   
    autoProcessQueue: true,

    success: function( file, response ) {
        var return_value = response;
        var old_value = $('#listing_images').val();
        if(old_value=="" || old_value==" " || old_value==null){
            var new_value = return_value;
        }else{
            var new_value = old_value+","+return_value;
        }
        $('#listing_images').val(new_value);
    },


  // The setting up of the dropzone

  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    //alert after success 

    this.on('queuecomplete', function( file, resp ){
        //alert('hahahahahaha');
    });
    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.

    document.getElementById("create_listing_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.


    });
    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead

    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.

    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
    });

    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {

      // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.

      // Redirect user or notify of success.

    });

    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {

      // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.

      // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error

    });

  }
}
  </script>
```

the code has this parth which is used to append the new filename into hidden field so that i can save those names in database then. but the problem is that when i click on delete button i need to delete the name of that file from the hidden field too. I am getting an encrypted name from the server.

```
success: function( file, response ) {
        var return_value = response;
        var old_value = $('#listing_images').val();
        if(old_value=="" || old_value==" " || old_value==null){
            var new_value = return_value;
        }else{
            var new_value = old_value+","+return_value;
        }
        $('#listing_images').val(new_value);
    },
```

I don't need the exact code. I just need a method by which i can pass the new filename to a function when i click on delete button. this should not prevent the delete from doing it default function

Answer (score 0):

well i found an answer . just update the success part according to your need. but as in my case i needed the image name as id of preview element. it will be done in this way.

```
success: function( file, response ) {
        var return_value = response;
        var old_value = $('#listing_images').val();
        if(old_value=="" || old_value==" " || old_value==null){
            var new_value = return_value;
             file.previewElement.id = response;
        }else{
            file.previewElement.id = response;
            var new_value = old_value+","+return_value;
        }
        $('#listing_images').val(new_value);    
    },
```

to change the value of list after delete button just add the following code in dropzone.js file(just the way i did it).
the code starts from line number 274. just change it from this

```
removeFileEvent = (function(_this) {
            return function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              if (file.status === Dropzone.UPLOADING) {
                return Dropzone.confirm(_this.options.dictCancelUploadConfirmation, function() {
                  return _this.removeFile(file);
                });
              } else {
                if (_this.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation) {
                  return Dropzone.confirm(_this.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation, function() {

                  return _this.removeFile(file);

                  });
                } else {

                 return _this.removeFile(file);

                }
              }
            };
          })(this);
          _ref2 = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-remove]");
          _results = [];
          for (_k = 0, _len2 = _ref2.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
            removeLink = _ref2[_k];
            _results.push(removeLink.addEventListener("click", removeFileEvent));

          }
          return _results;
        }
      },
```

to this(just four lines added. do it carefully, otherwise you can mess up all)

```
removeFileEvent = (function(_this) {
            return function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              if (file.status === Dropzone.UPLOADING) {
                return Dropzone.confirm(_this.options.dictCancelUploadConfirmation, function() {
                  return _this.removeFile(file);
                });
              } else {
                if (_this.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation) {
                  return Dropzone.confirm(_this.options.dictRemoveFileConfirmation, function() {
                    var id = $(this).closest("div").prop("id");
                    update_img_list(id);
                  return _this.removeFile(file);

                  });
                } else {
                     var id = $(this).closest("div").prop("id");
                    update_img_list(id);
                 return _this.removeFile(file);

                }
              }
            };
          })(this);
          _ref2 = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-remove]");
          _results = [];
          for (_k = 0, _len2 = _ref2.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
            removeLink = _ref2[_k];
            _results.push(removeLink.addEventListener("click", removeFileEvent));

          }
          return _results;
        }
      },
```

add this function at the end of file change ('#listing_images') to ('#id_of_your_field_which_contains_the_list')

```
function update_img_list(id){

  var list = $('#listing_images').val();
  separator = ",";
  var values = list.split(separator);
  for(var i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++) {
    if(values[i] == id) {
      values.splice(i, 1);
      $('#listing_images').val(values.join(separator)) ;
    }
  }
  return list;

}
```